# SQL Server CE error - only on compiled code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, error-handling, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a strange error which causes my application to crash. It only happens when compiled and installed via a click-once and not when debugging in Visual Studio.

Viewing the event log gives me this:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" /> 
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID> 
    <Level>4</Level> 
    <Task>0</Task> 
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-04-27T14:51:30.000000000Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>6471</EventRecordID> 
    <Channel>Application</Channel> 
    <Computer>me.local</Computer> 
    <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
    <Data /> 
    <Data>0</Data> 
    <Data>CLR20r3</Data> 
    <Data>Not available</Data> 
    <Data>0</Data> 
    <Data>calibration certificate builder</Data> 
    <Data>1.0.0.0</Data> 
    <Data>553e4aaa</Data> 
    <Data>System.Data.SqlServerCe</Data> 
    <Data>3.5.8080.0</Data> 
    <Data>4b743b2d</Data> 
    <Data>e3</Data> 
    <Data>0</Data> 
    <Data>System.ArgumentNullException</Data> 
    <Data /> 
    <Data>C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\WER80E0.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml</Data> 
    <Data>C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_pick_cert_e053eebdc3d787d726058a9b0d3405c6f279444_3b258dcb</Data> 
    <Data /> 
    <Data>0</Data> 
    <Data>e12fbed6-ecec-11e4-b276-24fd52358985</Data> 
    <Data>65</Data> 
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I am unsure how to handle this. I have looked through my code and it does not appear to be an issue there. It does seem to be within the SQL Server CE code somewhere but I have been unable to find it.

I also pushed the `event.ExceptionObject` string to a text file and got this:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>          at System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Object obj)
>          at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>          at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.Finalize()

Can anyone help me interpret this?

I have removed the use of the SQL CE services from other threads. I also removed the disposing of the SQL CE connection and also the finally blocks but the error logs remain the same.

Is the disposal of the connection causing an issue?

Comment: Likely not directly related, but: you are disposing of your SQL command (and likely other resources such as the SQLCeConnection) through their finalizer, instead of having them in a `using` block and disposing of them when you are done with them. I would also check your configuration for paths, etc. that may be different for your installed app and finally, I suspect that you are using the `try { .... } catch { /* do nothing, not even log the error */ }` pattern.

Comment: Yes I am doing that and using try/catch pattern. I will look at the disposal of the connection too. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot share command and connection objects across threads

Comment: @ErikEJ I wasn't aware I was doing this? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Not sure you are, but you *are* using threads

Comment: @ErikEJ Ok, thanks. I'll make sure I am not.

Comment: I removed the new thread from the application but it made no difference to the error or the error logs...

Comment: Are you setting the connection = Nothing, or is this just .NET deciding when to dispose?

Comment: At the moment I am using the the datasets and binding provided within Visual Studio. There are multiple databases being queried. I am not disposing ofthe connections myself.

Comment: Can you show a little of the code in your question.  We can guess at what you are doing but seeing will help a lot.

Comment: I am not sure what code to show you as I cannot track down exactly where the problem arises. I thought it may be something to do with the SQL CE database, Microsoft Sync framework and a compatibility issue with windows. If i find some code that may be an issue I will post it for sure, but the problem pops up at different times and in different forms.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are trying to connect with SQL database using windows authentication connection string and that person does not have access to sql database. Try to change the connection string with an user ID and password. Change from `"Data Source=URDATABASE;Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE;Integrated Security=True"` to `"Data Source=URDATABASE;Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE;Uid=UrUserID;Pwd=MyPassWord;"`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have just seen it. I am querying a local SQL CE database and my connection string is:`Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.sdf;Max Database Size=4091` When querying and syncing to the remote database the connection string  `Data Source=MYIPADDRESS;Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=MYPASSWORD`.